# Avoiding N+1 Queries When Serializing Model With Property Referencing Reverse Foreign Key Relationship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I currently have an issue where neither Django's `prefetch_related()` nor `prefetch_related_objects()` are sufficient in optimizing a Django Rest Framework serialization and I'm curious if anyone here has some ideas!

To visualize the situation I'm in, suppose I have three models, linked as such:

```
class VotableObjectExampleParent(models.Model):
    #several other fields redacted here#

class VotableObjectExample(models.Model):
    #several other fields redacted here#
    votableobjectexampleparent = models.ForeignKey('VotableObjectExampleParent', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'votableobjectexamples')
    @property
    def total_votes(self):
        return self.votableobjectexample_votes.aggregate(sum = Sum("vote"))["sum"] or 0

class VotableObjectExample_Vote(models.Model):
    #several other fields redacted here#
    votablebjectexample = models.ForeignKey('VotableObjectExample', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'votablebjectexample_votes')
    vote = models.IntegerField(choices = [(-1, "down"), (1, "up")])
```

I then have appropriate (and functional!) DRF serializers such as the ones shown:

```
class VotableObjectExampleParent_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   related_votableobjectexamples = Idea_Proposal_Serializer(source = "votableobjectexamples", many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = VotableObjectExampleParent
        fields = ['related_votableobjectexamples'] #other fields would normally be in this array
        read_only_fields = fields

class VotableObjectExample_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = VotableObjectExample
        fields = ['total_votes'] #other fields would normally be in this array
        read_only_fields = fields
```

At first, I would simply call the parent serializer (`VotableObjectExampleParent_Serializer`) in the view:

```
#assume a variable I already have called this_pk is correct and available for use
serializer = VotableObjectExampleParent_Serializer(VotableObjectExampleParent.objects.get(pk = this_pk), many = True)
JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
```

This produces 100% correct JSON for my needs, but I quickly run into the issue of N+1 queries as there are plenty of `VotableObjectExamples` and `VotableObjectExample_Votes` and, in real life, plenty of other nested, reverse-foreign-key relations to traverse. I was able to drop the ~30 queries this takes (which could easily expand to 100s quickly) to ~20 by using `prefetch_related_objects()` to replace the code block above:

```
this_votableobjectparent = [VotableObjectExampleParent.objects.get(pk = this_pk)]
prefetch_related_objects(this_votableobjectparent, 'votableobjectexamples', 'votableobjectexamples__votablebjectexample_votes')
JSONRenderer().render(VotableObjectExampleParent_Serializer(this_votableobjectparent[0]).data)
```

Using the fantastic `Django-Debug-Toolbar` I can verify that queries are correctly made to prefetch for the correct IDs across all specified models above. But all this being said, **there are still N+1 queries being made only for calculating the `total_votes` field(s)**.

I've tried what seems like a million different suggestions from different StackOverflow threads, such as switching from using `aggregate` to `annotate`:

```
@property
def total_votes(self):
    query = self.votablebjectexample_votes.annotate(sum = Sum("vote")).values_list('sum',flat=True)
        if query:
            return query[0]
        else:
            return 0
```

I've also tried adding a custom `Manager` for each Model with a `total_votes` field, moving the total_votes calculation to a get_queryset method. Unfortunately, in this case, DRF complains it can't find the `total_votes` field at all, which I suspect is because the field is no longer explicitly declared in the model the `ModelSerializer` points to.

Does anyone know where to go from here? Perhaps there's a straightforward solution, but this doesn't seem like a particularly uncommon issue for someone to have, so I'm a bit surprised it takes this much tinkering to produce something efficient and scalable.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: scalable: put a job in a queue to calculate and store the total votes on each vote event rather than calcualting it at query time. alternatively, implement a cache of the query and insert a job to update it at each vote event.

Comment: @bryan60 brilliant, that makes a ton of sense. I am still curious how to prefetch_related  in a way that optimizes a property with a lookup in it in general (who knows when that problem could legitimately arise!), but I must admit you are correct here in solving my particular issue.

Comment: I need to think through how I'd write the SQL here. It feels doable to optimize this but it might be the use of the `@property` decorator that is messing with the ORM.  I'd try to figure it out without that complication first and then see if you can put that part in again after the fact. DRF is great but the serializers build some stupid queries left to their own devices.

Comment: there should be a way to make it calculate and annotate all the vote totals in one query though rather than in a query for each votable object.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the root cause of `N+1` is the `VotableObjectExample.total_votes` property because `self.votableobjectexample_votes` will create another query.

- When you use `prefetch_related`, it gets stored in `instance._prefetched_objects_cache` (be wary it will cause `AttributeError` if no prefetch is done). If `instance._prefetched_objects_cache` exists, it is a `dict` of `{"<related_name>": <queryset>, ...}`.
- Another point is even if you use `instance._prefetched_objects_cache`, adding more query in the cached queryset will create another query. In this case, running the line below will result in another query since aggregate is a different query:

  ```
  self._prefetched_objects_cache["votableobjectexample_votes"].aggregate(sum = Sum("vote"))["sum"]
  ```

---

So to sum it up, you can try this one out:

```
class VotableObjectExample(models.Model):
    #several other fields redacted here#

    @property
    def total_votes(self):
        # Check if prefetch cache exists
        if hasattr(self, "_prefetched_objects_cache") and self._prefetched_objects_cache.get("votableobjectexample_votes"):
            total_votes = 0

            for votableobjectexample_vote in votableobjectexample_votes:
                total_votes += votableobjectexample_vote.vote

            return total_votes

        # Still need this if `prefetch_related` wasn't called
        return self.votableobjectexample_votes.aggregate(sum = Sum("vote"))["sum"] or 0
```